# Realm.io irrational big data usage on android

Tags: android, realm, filesize

I using Realm db in my app, and i noticed the default.realm file grows to size ~150MB after i download and store all entity what i need in the app. The data is not big in size, but big in quantity (~800 piece of json object, containing 5 simple strings and integers)

I downloaded the data file and opened in RealmBrowser. I found the 'Export to compressed realm' option, this have a 150kB realm output. I copied this file to the app, and its working correctly.

I googled a lot for the solve, only i found is the Realm.compactRealm() method, but i don't found any detailed documentation how can i use that.

Finally if i close the app foced via task manager and restart the compactRealm() method compresses the data file to size 236kB.

Please help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217476/android-realm-large-file-size http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33090787/realm-with-huge-data

Comment: This happens if you don't close your Realm instances.

Comment: Checkout my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217476/android-realm-large-file-size/42959238#42959238